# printing data from phone in android

Tags: android

In my android application i would like to allow the user to print the data on phone  to the nearest printer on click of print button.

Is it possible in android.How could i get the printers nearby?

Please share your valuable suggestions.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: do you get the solution.if you got plz look into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23557722/print-from-your-android-application-with-bluetooth-printer

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want [send2printer](http://www.androlib.com/android.application.com-rcreations-send2printer-jExq.aspx), which apparently contains an API that can be used by 3rd-party apps (I guess that's where you come in).